# Ошибка запроса UPDATE. Invalid column name 'ФИО'

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, update

```
db.OpenConnection();

                string sql1 = "UPDATE Пользователи SET Фото = @img Where ФИО = @fio";

                    var Command = new SqlCommand(sql1, db.getConnection());
                    Command.Parameters.Add("@fio", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Image.Save(memoryStream, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
                        Command.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    }

                    if (Command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Данные успешно занесены");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Данные не занесены");
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй выполнить запрос непосредственно в базе.
Может там в названии столбца "ФИО" "О" английская, а не русская.
Возможно есть смысл обернуть названия таблицы и столбцов в кавычки:

```
UPDATE "Пользователи" SET "Фото" = @img Where "ФИО" = @fio
```

Comment: *Возможно есть смысл обернуть названия таблицы и столбцов в кавычки* Судя по коду, у автора SQL Server. В этом случае правильнее использовать квадратные скобки, а не двойные кавычки...

Comment: Двойные кавычки - стандарт, квадратные скобки - только в MS SQL. Я стараюсь придерживаться стандарта. Сюда может зайти человек, не с MS SQL, но с подобным вопросом, поэтому ответ с кавычками более универсальный.

Comment: Согласен, отсутствие тега конкретной СУБД - косяк автора вопроса. *Сюда может зайти человек, не с MS SQL, но с подобным вопросом, поэтому ответ с кавычками более универсальный* Если этот человек будет использовать MySQL/MariaDB, то у него скорее всего именно двойная кавычка приведёт к проблемам, для её использования нужна настройка SQL Mode. Так что стандарты - они сами по себе, а разработчики только обеспечивают возможность сделать код совместимым, но не всегда в дефолтной конфигурации.